# Delete Entrys in different Tables MysQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to figure out, how to delete some entries in the database with INNER JOIN.

I have 2 different Tables, USER and BLOGS

I'm trying to delete all entries in BLOGS, when the entry belongs to a user, which does not exist. So in USER table there are all users listed with a unique ID. This same ID also is in table BLOGS.

A Query like this would work, but I guess this is not even a correct mysql query:

```
delete from BLOGS where `id` does not exist in USER;
```

I know, the command "does not exist" doesn't really work.

Any Idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
DELETE FROM BLOGS WHERE `id`  NOT IN
   (SELECT id FROM `USER`);
```

Comment: Sorry, bad solution, and wrong, too. If at all it would be `...NOT IN (SELECT id FROM user);`

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') AS idList FROM `USER` this query gives the string of id's like (1,2,3....)

Comment: @tombom thanks, i correct it and have you any idea why cant i can use this query?

Comment: You can use it, but it's slower than mine.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to do a left join and see which entry has no corresponding row in the other table.

```
DELETE FROM 
blogs
LEFT JOIN users ON blogs.id = users.id
WHERE users.id IS NULL;
```

Another syntax close to yours is possible, but it's not performant, since for every row in blogs table, the whole users table is read (assuming there's no index).